# Search Everything plugin integration

Tags: plugins, search

The search on my wordpress site is resulting in a 404. When I hit the search button it tries to open a php file in a path that does not exist wordpress/wordpress/index.php. I dont know how that was configured or where to reset the search button action code.

I assumed that installing "search everything plugin" will solve my search problems, it did. The test does a wonderful search. But I need to figure out how to fix the search button issue.

I have just started work on wordpress and dont know php.

Edit : I just did a "view source" for my home page and found

```
<form id="searchform" class="searchform" method="get" action="http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/index.php">
```

I also did a

```
sudo grep -r "searchForm" .
```

To find the source of all my pain,

```
./wp-content/themes/graphene/searchform.php:<form id="searchform" class="searchform" method="get" action="<?php echo get_home_url(), $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

Seems like the url is getting its value from PHP-SELF

So I search where PHP-SELF is getting its value from

```
sudo grep --exclude-dir=.svn -r "SERVER\['PHP_SELF'\] = " .
./wp-includes/load.php:     $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = $PHP_SELF = preg_replace( '/(\?.*)?$/', '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );
./wp-login.php:     $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = str_replace( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
```

Now, seems like REQUEST_URI is used to initialize PHP_SELF
OR
Its PATH_INFO and PHP_SELF

As I dig further it gets more complex. My question is, **What is expected to be the value of PHP_SELF.**

```
sudo grep --exclude-dir=.svn -r "SERVER\['REQUEST_URI'\] = " .
./wp-includes/load.php:         $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL'];
./wp-includes/load.php:         $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'];
./wp-includes/load.php:                 $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
./wp-includes/load.php:                 $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
./wp-admin/link-manager.php:    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = remove_query_arg(array('deleted'), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
./wp-admin/upload.php:  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = remove_query_arg(array('posted'), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
./wp-admin/upload.php:  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = remove_query_arg(array('attached'), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
./wp-admin/upload.php:  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = remove_query_arg(array('deleted'), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
./wp-admin/upload.php:  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = remove_query_arg(array('trashed'), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
./wp-admin/upload.php:  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = remove_query_arg(array('untrashed'), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
./wp-admin/upload.php:  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = remove_query_arg(array('message'), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
./wp-admin/plugins.php:$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = remove_query_arg(array('error', 'deleted', 'activate', 'activate-multi', 'deactivate', 'deactivate-multi', '_error_nonce'), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
./wp-admin/edit-tags.php:<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = remove_query_arg(array('message'), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
./wp-admin/network/themes.php:$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = remove_query_arg( $temp_args, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
./wp-admin/network/site-users.php:$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = remove_query_arg( 'update', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
./wp-admin/network/site-themes.php:$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = remove_query_arg( $temp_args, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
./wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugins-list-table.php:            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = add_query_arg('s', stripslashes($_REQUEST['s']) );
./wp-admin/edit.php:$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = remove_query_arg( array('locked', 'skipped', 'updated', 'deleted', 'trashed', 'untrashed'), $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
./wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/lib/W3/PgCacheFlush.php:        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $url;
./wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/lib/W3/PgCacheFlush.php:        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $request_uri;
```

Comment: You may be looking for the wrong thing. `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is a system variable, which is used within Wordpress, not created by it. See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php for more detail.

Comment: I hardcoded action="http://localhost/wordpress" and my search worked. So now the issue is narrowed down to the action value. Now my question is, shouldn't I be using macros instead of hardcode for the search "action" value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Search Everything](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/) doesn't modify the search form, it only modifies the queries a search performs. You won't see any changes on the front end except within the contents of the search results.

Comment: But my search button still displays something crazy like wordpress/wordpress/index.php not found. I wonder why.

Comment: @Siddharth, perhaps you should reword you question to tell us what you are seeing and what you expect to be seeing and please be more specific than "something crazy like...".

Comment: @JohnGardeniers I have improved my question to be more specific and detailed.